# textAlign right not working for custom vertical tab label in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am overriding the tabs of material-ui to have a vertical view of the tabs. However, I also want the label (text) of these tabs to align to the right so it looks more uniform. I've tried every kind of styling but still cannot get it to work.

```
<VerticalTabs
      value={tabValue}
      indicatorColor={'primary'}
      onChange={this.handleTabChange}


    >
      <MyTab
        disableRipple
        lableStyle={{float: 'right'}} <----- doesn't work
        label="Sourcing"
      />
        <MyTab
        disableRipple
        lableStyle={{float: 'right'}}
        label="Production"
      />
      <MyTab
        disableRipple
        lableStyle={{float: 'right'}}
        label="Shipping"
      />
      <MyTab
        disableRipple
        lableStyle={{float: 'right'}}
        label="Sales"
      />
    </VerticalTabs>
```

override styling:

```
const VerticalTabs = withStyles(theme => ({
  flexContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  indicator: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  tabsRoot: {
    textAlign: 'right'
  }

}))(Tabs)

const MyTab = withStyles(theme => ({

  root: {
  borderRight: '2px solid lightgray',
  textAlign: 'right'


  },
  selected: {
    color: '#4ABDAC',
    borderRight: '3px solid #4ABDAC',
    textAlign: 'right'


  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 20,


    textTransform: 'initial',
  },


}))(Tab);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to align the label text to the right side of the tab container?

Comment: Try `<Tab classes={{label: {textAlign: "right"}}} ... />` or `<Tab classes={{labelContainer: {textAlign: "right"}}} ... />`. You should look into https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes

Comment: @Titus tried it and it didn't work :(

Comment: Try to add that style to the `wrapper` (`<Tab classes={{wrapper: {textAlign: "right"}}} ... />`). If it doesn't work, take a look at the [component's implementation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Tab/Tab.js) and see what classes you need to override and what styles to use.

Comment: So `classes` should apply a class to it. Doing `<Tab classes={{label: 'my-custom-class'}} />` will apply `.my-custom-class` to it, letting you target it with CSS, so that you can `.my-custom-class { text-align: right; }`

Comment: You didn't show in your question how you are displaying the tab contents, so I'm not fully clear on what you want the end result to look like. [Here's a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nwmw5j2yo0) with what you provided so far. Please update it with where you are at so far to show the overall layout you are trying to achieve. Then include the new sandbox URL in your question.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I was using an older version of material-ui. after upgrading to the latest version (v3) I was able to get the text to align to the right. thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the lates version of material-ui fixed this issue (v3.9.1 currently)

Answer (score 3):

The Tab component in material ui has a wrapper with align-items: "center" css(MuiTab-wrapper) applied to it. You need to override this and change it to "flex-start" or "flex-end"
https://material-ui.com/api/tab/

```
wrapper: {
    alignItems: "flex-start"
}
```